# Python linked list, remove function iter

Tags: python, string, linked-list

```
def remove(lst,value):
    curr = lst.head
    while not isinstance(curr, EmptyNode):
        if curr.data == value:
            curr.data=curr.nxt.data
            curr.nxt =curr.data.nxt
            lst.size -= 1
            return lst
        curr = curr.nxt
        return True
    return False
```

This function is supposed to remove a value that is given, and return a boolean value (True). For example if i input:

```
remove(lstA, 'b')
```

it should return True, but when i run my program, it is giving me this error message:

```
       curr.nxt =curr.data.nxt
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'nxt'
```

Any small hint would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error is because the data member of a node (of your linked list) i.e., `curr.data` is a string. Doing a `.nxt` on a string is not defined. What you should instead be doing is, a `.nxt` on a node object.

There are other issues with your code too:

- You say that if a value is found in the list, it should remove it and return true. But in your code there is a return statement within `if curr.data == value:` which means if the value to be removed is found, the method would return the list and not `True` as you are expecting it to.
- Further, looking at your code, if it does not find the value to be removed in the current node, it will increment the `curr` to the next node and return `True`
- You can not remove a node from the linked list when you are currently at that node (which seems to be the case in your code). You can do that only if you have a variable that holds the previous node. Since in your code, you do not save the previous node, you should be looking at `curr.next.data`. In other words you should be checking `if curr.next.data == value:`. You need to handle boundary conditions accordingly.

Comment: well i tried what you said to check if cure.next.data == value:, seems to be working but it is not outputting the boolean, it is outputting <__main__.MyList object at 0x30e3930>.

Comment: `<__main__.MyList object at 0x30e3930>` implies the `return lst` in the `if` block is being executed. Check my point 1 as to why your code will not return `True`

Comment: ohh, i see so just change the lst, to True, now it does, but what if i want to remove an element from the list, that does not exist? It should return False, but for my code it is not returning anything